# JavaScript finding and returning the longest word in a sentence only letters counts numbers will be ignored

Tags: javascript

```
const longestWord = (sentence)=>{
var words = sentence.replace(/0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9/gi, " ").split(' '); 
  var longestWord = words[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
    var currentWord = words[i];  
    if (longestWord.length < currentWord.length) {
      longestWord = currentWord;
    }
  }
  return longestWord;
}
```

hey guys I needed to find the longest word in the sentence only letters count now I have searched here and came up with this code I do understand in but it is not working with sentences that have number in words like this sentence "I'm not hung1ry 12345" but in this sentence it did work " I'm not hungry 12345"
so is there is any idea to make it work?

Comment: _"came up with this code I do understand"_ - Then you should be able to tell us why you replace numbers with a space?

Comment: Replace with an empty string and not a space -> `.replace(/.../gi, "")`

Comment: yes I understand now thanks I did it with out space and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var words = sentence.replace(/0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9/gi, " ").split(' ');
```

replace this line with this one:

```
var words = sentence.replace(/0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9/gi, "").split(' ');
```